# Django template multiple tables with only slightly modified data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I want to display two tables on my page where only one column is modified and all the others are the same. I was wondering if there's any other way which is more efficient than simply looping two-times and creating the table two times?

What I would do right now is:

```
# Example models
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    score = models.Integerfield()

    SCORETYPES = (
    (1, 'initial'),
    (2, 'current'),
    )

    scoreType = models.Integerfield(choices=SCORETYPES)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Answer: " + scoreType
```

In my view I would link the question with the answers as so:

```
# Example view
questions = Question.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('answer_set', to_attr='answers')).all()
```

Which means that my question object would look like this for each question

```
question.answers = [<Answer: Initial>, <Answer: Current>]
```

and then in my template I would print them like this

```
# Example template
{% for question in questions %}
    {% for answer in question.answers %}
        <p>{{ answer.scoreType }}: {{ answer.score }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This would work but now I want to create a table for all the initial scores and one table for all the current scores so you get something like this:

```
Initial Scores

Question    Score
Q1          2
Q2          3

Current Scores

Question    Score
Q1          1
Q2          4
```

As you can see this would require me to use a for-loop two times and check each time if the scoretype is either 1 or 2. Is there a more efficient way to do this or is this the way to go? I have a lot of questions and I would like to work as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use two distinct querysets, filterer on `Answer.scoreType`, ie:

```
# views

def myview(request, ...):
    qs = Question.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('answer_set', to_attr='answers'))
    initial = qs.filter(answer__scoreType=1)
    current = qs.filter(answer_scoreType=2)
    context = {"initial": initial, "current": current)
    # etc
```

Then

```
# template:

<h1>Initial scores</h1>
{% for q in initial %}
   {% for answer in q.answers %}
    # ...
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

<h1>Current scores</h1>
{% for q in current %}
   {% for answer in q.answers %}
    # ...
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

BUT this means you'll have two db queries, which might not be optimal either (depending on your dataset size etc).

Another solution would be to filter out your querysets manually in the view but this will begin to be tricky if you want to keep your queryset ordered by question, will eat more memory, and will possibly end up being slower than issuing two distinct queries (here again, depending on your dataset size etc).

So to make a long story short, the "right" solution really depends on your actual dataset - specially how many questions / answers you typically have in a view. If those are very small datasets, filtering in the view or even directly in the template might be fast enough, but the relative perfs of pure python code or (worse) template code VS your SQL db builtin filtering will very quickly make the first option (2 distinct queries) faster.

Comment: Wouldn't this make two extra queries to the database because you're using filter on a queryset?

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans yes, that's what I was about to mention actually ;)

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans cf my edited answer. Just for the sake of completeness, remember that django Querysets are lazy - you only hit the database when you actually start iterating over it - so you'll only have _one_ extra query (=> you'll have two queries total, instead of single one).

Comment: Ah, I see. That would indeed be one query more than I'm using now. Thanks for your edit, I'm guessing it would be faster to do one more query than to it is to do the filtering in the template. I will try it out. Thanks!